# in sql how the dbms execute the query

Tags: mysql

In nor_employees table, when I execute the below query,no rows are selected.

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, employee_id
FROM nor_employees
WHERE employee_id NOT IN
(SELECT  reports_to FROM NOR_EMPLOYEES);
```

for the below query it is getting.

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, employee_id
FROM nor_employees
WHERE employee_id NOT IN
(SELECT  reports_to FROM NOR_EMPLOYEES where reports_to is not null);
```

can you explain why?

Comment: It's because you have different `WHERE` clauses...all we can say...

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3 value logic.

NOT IN clause is translated to not equal, i.e.

```
select * 
from table 
where col not in (10,20 )
```

it is translated by interpreter to

```
select * 
from table 
where col <> 10 and col <> 20
```

In case, if one of values in the list null then we have *col <> Null*. It always False. As result no rows in result set